# Convert Spring BindingResult to JSON?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I'm trying to export a [Spring Framework BindingResult object](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html) to JSON to send it back to a web client that we're building.   I really only need the list of errors:

```
List<ObjectError> getAllErrors()
```

Unfortunately, even this seems to have a lot of self-referencing internal links which result in a JsonMappingException error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: [snip]
```

Is there a simple, "canned" way of doing this or do I need to write something?   I'm not averse to writing something but it would be nice if there was something like:

```
BindingResult.getAllErrors().asJson();
```

Comment: http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/09/generating-json-error-object-responses-with-spring-web-mvc

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - thanks, if you will post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: I just looked something up that I thought would be helpful. I haven't actually gone through and prepared a well-thought out answer. If you have a solution, you can post it yourself as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, if I find one (or invent one) I will do that.